# Heroku, golang asset compilation should happen during builds. But how?

Tags: go, heroku, deployment, asset-pipeline, assets

I'm using Heroku and Golang.

I have one or many `.scss` files and I use a golang library to generate a `.css` from them.

What I don't understand is how to generate the `.css` file during Heroku build step.

As stated here https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/release-phase#design-considerations:

> Asset compilation should happen during builds considering the dyno filesystem is ephemeral.

I don't want to commit my generated files.

Am I wrong?

Comment: see something like https://github.com/gobuffalo/packr or go-bindata

Comment: It's the same. Both need to do something before build. I don't want to commit anything generated.

Answer (score 1):

Heroku supports Docker deploy https://devcenter.heroku.com/categories/deploying-with-docker

It means that any transpilations you can do on "Docker build" step

Comment: Thanks a lot Alex, but I prefer not to use Docker on Heroku because it decrease the performances by being a layer further in the middle of the daily req/resp.